# TCL regsub replace last / in file name

Tags: tcl, regsub

To replace the last `/`in a file name with `:` I tried following code.

```
set x a/b/c
regsub {.*(\/)\S+$} $x {:}
```

The undesired result is `:`.

The desired result is `a/b:c`

Examples:

```
a -> a
a/b -> a:b
aa/b -> aa:b
aa/bb/.../dd/e -> aa/bb/.../dd:e
```

Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regular expression, you can say

```
set new [regsub {/([^/]+)$} $x {:\1}]       ;# ==> a/b:c

foreach d {a a/b aa/b aa/bb/.../dd/e} {puts "$d => [regsub {/([^/]+)$} $d {:\1}]"}
# a => a
# a/b => a:b
# aa/b => aa:b
# aa/bb/.../dd/e => aa/bb/.../dd:e
```

Or, use the [`file` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm)

```
set new [file dirname $x]:[file tail $x]    ;# ==> a/b:c
```

The problem with the 2nd option is if the string does not contain a slash, you get `a` => `.:a` so you need to do something like this:

```
foreach d {a a/b aa/b aa/bb/.../dd/e} {
    set new [expr {[string first / $d] == -1 ? $d : "[file dirname $d]:[file tail $d]"}]
    puts "$d -> $new"
}
```